# Field grouping in case worker dies in Storm

Tags: apache, apache-storm

I have a use case where I am using a local cache to maintain counters for certain ids. I did a `fieldsGrouping("spout", new Fields("id"))` in Topology class. 
Let's say `id1` was always getting processed in `processingBolt` on `worker1` and `id2` was always getting processed in `processingBolt` on `worker2`. If `worker2` dies , will `id2` start getting processed on `worker1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Storm used the abstraction of tasks internally. If you use fieldsGrouping, each ID is mapped to a task, and task are executed by bolt instances.

If one bold instance fails, Storm will move the task to other bolt instances.